# ExecuteStoreQuery return multiple rows how can i get it into an IList or List

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, c#-3.0

I have a stored procedure that returns a dynamic query, e,g if i pass some value to its `id` parameter it return me a dynamic query like

```
Select * from someTable tbl where tbl.Id=51
```

then i execute this query using `ExecuteStoreQuery` like

```
string query = container.CreateQuery<string>(
                    "SELECT VALUE DB.Store.GetQuery(@ID) FROM {1}",
                    new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("ID", 51)
                ).First();

object lists = container.ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(query);
```

the problem is `container.ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(query);` returns multiple rows which i want to get into a list, how can i do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a model of type you want to return the results like

```
public class mymodel{

public int _key{get;set;}
public string _value{get;set;}
}
```

where `_key` and `_value` correspond to the columns of the returned result

execute the query `ExecuteStoreQuery` also return the result `AsQueryable`

```
 container.ExecuteStoreQuery<mymodel>(query).AsQueryable().ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer. I was had a class with just members variables (eg: `public int key;`) and it didn't work, but when I changed the members to properties by adding the `{get; set;}` it worked great.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but it looks like you are looking for `ToList` method:

```
List<MyEntity> list = container.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyEntity>(query).ToList();
```

The bigger problems is `object` in your code - if you really mean `object` type it will not work. You must provide a real type (either mapped entity, complex type or custom class with public properties using same names as columns in result set) otherwise EF will not fill data for you.

Comment: Where did you learn this from?

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures can be imported in your Entity Model. That will result in a function on your `ObjectContext` that you can call from your code.

When you map the SP you can let EF map the result of your SP to an Entity. If you don't have a matching entity EF can determine the resulting columns for your stored procedure and map that a complex type.

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx) that explains this.

Comment: tnx for replying i know the SP can be mapped to the entity but i am only using the SP to generate the query then i am executing the query by using `context.ExecuteStoreQuery`